# How to find an element using xpath for multiple divs

Tags: c#, selenium

Having a little issue trying to select an element below:

```
<div class="x-layer x-combo-list " id="ext-gen452" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: visible; left: 89px; top: 66px; width: 398px; height: 20px;">
 <div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="ext-gen454" style="width: 398px; overflow: auto; height: 20px;">
  <div ext:qtip="xxxWebService@xxx.com" class="x-combo-list-item  x-combo-selected">xxxWebService@xxx.com
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

I want to be able to use ext:qtip = "xxxWebService@xxx.com" but it keeps stating it cannot find the element, can I have a little guidance on what I need to do in order to be able to find the element please?

```
    WebDriverWait waitAgent = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    waitAgent.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(("//div/div/div*[@ext:qtip='xxxWebService@xxx.com]'))))
        .Click();
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @BruceyBandit, have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel there is a small issue with the `xpath` you used as:

```
By.XPath(("//div/div/div*[@ext:qtip='xxxWebService@xxx.com]')))
```

You have used `div*` where `*` seems unnecessary. Moreover the closing `"` was missing and the closing `'` was misplaced. Again as you are traversing down the `DOM` through different `div` as in `//div/div/div` where we would have prefered to use the `id` of the parent `div` which stands to be unique in the `DOM tree`. Hence the following code block using the attribute `ext:qtip = "xxxWebService@xxx.com"` as per your requirement may serve your purpose.

```
WebDriverWait waitAgent = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
waitAgent.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@id='ext-gen454']/div[@ext:qtip='xxxWebService@xxx.com']"))).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below xpath :-

```
//div[@class='x-combo-list-item  x-combo-selected']
```

As I seen you also trying to search with email id then you can use XPath as below 
:-

```
(//div[contains(.,'xxxWebService@xxx.com')])[3]
```

OR more specific and id is not dynamic :-

```
//div[@id='ext-gen452']/div/div[@class='x-combo-list-item  x-combo-selected']
```

You can replace id with class if id dynamic or not unique. same with class

If above solution also not work then use wait .. there must be a wait issue

Hope it will help you